# main-domain of WordPress keeps redirecting to subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, deployment

I was in process of deploying my WordPress website `mysite.com/NewSite` to `mysite.com` during the deployment I messed up something and my main site has started redirecting from `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/NewSite`.

I have deleted everything from root folder, checked cPanel redirects section etc but everything looks fine. I also created .htaccess file under public_html folder but still no luck.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My web site is presently down.

Comment: I tried to revert everything but still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: This could be a browser cache issue. Try it in another browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure these two settings in your "options" table are correct:

```
siteurl
home
```

From the database admin, you could update them with:

```
update wp_options set option_value='http://example.com' where option_name='siteurl';
update wp_options set option_value='http://example.com' where option_name='home';
```

EDIT:  If you've already changed these settings, and confirmed that there isn't a .htaccess redirect happening, the next place to look is in the web server's configuration for any redirects. These could have been previously placed in the VirtualHost configuration file for example.

Answer (score 1):

Update the options table in MySQL database (in phpmyadmin ...)

Most options are also available in WP admin, but in your case you cannot access wp-admin right now

Comment: As site root has nothing in it other than a sub folder... Isn't it should go to error page? why its still redirecting...

Comment: I have checked wp-options and everything looks good there... when I install a fresh copy of wordpress... mysite.com/wp-admin is accessible and all of its settings but as soon as I hit `mysite.com` it redirects to `mysite.com/NewSite`